# How do I demonstrate a legal right or claim to my great-grandfathers death certificate?

Tags: new-york-state, death

Jurisdiction:  New York State (Broome County)

I am trying to obtain a copy of my great-grandfather's death certificate (died 1951 in Broome County NY) in support of a dual citizenship application.

As I am not a parent, sibling, or child of the deceased, I cannot request a copy of the death certificate.   However, no person parent, sibling or child of the deceased is currently alive. Therefore, NY State Vital Records indicated that I need a 'court order' to receive a copy of the death certificate.

There is plenty of information about different petitions for Surrogate's Court relating to wills, estate and probate proceedings and petitions that require a death certificate be attached.  However, I cannot find guidance on how to petition the court for a order that NY Vital Records provide a certified copy of the death certificate to me.

Any insight on the next steps to petition Surrogate's Court is greatly appreciated.

Comment: You should be able to get it from [the state](https://www.health.ny.gov/vital_records/death.htm). That page says you can have a documented lawful right or claim. Would the agency that needs it, document that need?

Comment: FYI, this is a good question. I've encountered it in Colorado and as someone admitted in NYS I should know the answer, but I don't beyond what @mkennedy has provided because I haven't been involved in a probate case in NYS for many years and a lot of this is unwritten procedural practice of the agency.